# Selenium Webdriver - Login to the site - Multiple times & Site having binding for one browser and one user

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, webdriver

I am trying to code for login page. Security is such that system doesn't allow user to login in other browser or device. Binding is there for one browser and one user. If I try to login again creating browser instance again, system doesn't allow to login. Request you to suggest a solution as I need.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to reflect what your desired result is and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

your question is very unclear, you should tell details what you want, what you have tried etc. anyway as far as i understand, you can create Profiles in your browser.
normally selenium starts a very new browser every time (it erases any previous settings) , so you should create a Profile in browser and open that browser profile in your selenium.